# What is the alternate option of angular DomSanitizer(bypassSecurityTrustHtml)

Tags: javascript, css, angular

Getting XSS vulnerabilities during the build with the IT security team. So, in the (this.res) containing the video embedded code with script tags to run the video and its content. Please suggest any alternate solution.

**Import**

```
    import {
      Component,
      OnInit,
      ViewChild,
      SecurityContext,
    } from '@angular/core';
    
    import {DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

**Use the below code in your component:**

```
 ngOnInit() {
  this.res = `<div class="embed-container">
    <iframe
      src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/{{ include.id }}"
      width="700"
      height="480"
      frameborder="0"
      allowfullscreen="true">
    </iframe>
  </div>`

  this._domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.res)
  }
```

I tried using the this._domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.res) to load the video and content, am expecting the is there any API or alternative to this solution to XSS vulnerabilities.?

Answer (score 0):

Please review https://angular.io/guide/security.

In your case, HTML security seems to be overkill, URL security should be enough. Move the HTML code to the template. Then create a new variable which stores the iframe src URL, which needs to be trusted by `bypassSecurityTrustUrl()`.

**.ts:**

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.src = this._domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(`https://www.youtube.com/embed/${id}`);
}
```

**.html:**

```
<div class="embed-container">
  <iframe
      [src]="src"
      width="700"
      height="480"
      frameborder="0"
      allowfullscreen="true">
  </iframe>
</div>
```

Now attackers cannot inject malicious HTML code anymore.

Comment: @Dan If the solution worked well, you can vote accordingly and mark the answer as accepted. Thanks!

Comment: The given solution worked for me, thank you...